# C# ThreadPool wait on result

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, compiler-errors

I want to have a function to something similar:

```
public static V callAsyncAndWait<V>(Func<V> func)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj => 
    {
        V v = func.Invoke();                 
    });

    return v;
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't compile. What I want is to run the Func in another thread and return the result. How can I do that?

Comment: this does not make sense. Calling asynchronous means not blocking the caller thread, which is what you want. why not invoking the function in the calling thread? It really makes no difference

Comment: `callAsyncAndWait` is highly confusing. You want to start something asynchronously **or** wait for the process to be completed?

Comment: Possibly his control flow is something like: Start async task, execute something else, wait for result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use the new .NET 4.0 `Task` class instead. Here is a tutorial on how to return a result from the execution of `Task`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613.aspx

Practically you have a very convenient property called `Result`, which, upon invocation of the getter, will block until the result is available.

Comment: You can't use Tasks in DN 3.5 and yearly

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, it's the "new .NET 4.0 Task".

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't make too much sense. If the method is supposed to **wait** for the task to be finished, then you don't need a separate thread at all.

Something like "call async and **notify** when done" would make more sense:

```
void CallAsyncAndNotifyWhenDone<T>(Func<T> func, Action<T> callback)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj => 
    {
        T result = func();         
        callback(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use async patternt to do it:

```
public static V callAsyncAndWait<V>(Func<V> func)
{
  var asyncResult = func.BeginInvoke(null, null);

  asyncresult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

  return func.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
}
```